# Добавленеи и удаление из массива

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть ли метод или как можно сделать за минимальное количества кода.Добавление элемента в массив если его нету или удаление его если он есть.Нужна функиция которая принимает элемент и далее работает с массивом.

Comment: Три строчки кода. Пишите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function changeArray(arr, el) {
  return arr.includes(el)
    ? arr.filter(item => item !== el)
    : [...arr, el]
}

console.log(changeArray([1,2,3], 4))
console.log(changeArray([5,4,3], 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkValueArray(array, value) {
  let index = array.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) array.splice(index, 1);
  else array.push(value);
  return array;
}

console.log(checkValueArray([1, 2, 3], 8));
```